# How to insert customize check condition (eg JRE Check) in Package Maker, Mac

Tags: macos, packagemaker

Hi I am using Mac 10.6 i.e. snow leopard. I used Package Maker to create installer for my own application. The installer works fine. My application wants minimum JRE 1.6 (Java Runtime Environment). I want if my system do not have JRE1.6 or higher then the user should not be able to install the software. The system should show an error message and the url to the downloadable JRE.

What I have to do to get this type of functionality?

Thanks
Sunil Kumar Sahoo.

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done in the "[Product Package Requirements Pane](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/PackageMakerUserGuide/Workflow/Workflow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005371-CH1000-SW33)" of the PackageMaker application. Don't remember if JRE conditions are already defined.

Comment: No, JRE check is not mentioned there.